# How do I restore jQuery Chosen's data-placeholder when all options are unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using *jQuery Chosen* (and it works just fine).
But I am using the [nothing selected] state as an All-Selected state (see code below):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".chosen-select").chosen();
});
```

```css
.chosen-select{
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sinkolas.com/v2/funciones/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sinkolas.com/v2/funciones/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sinkolas.com/v2/funciones/FuncionesBellas.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sinkolas.com/v2/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.sinkolas.com/v2/chosen/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select id="xyz" data-placeholder="All" class="chosen-select" multiple="" tabindex="-1">
  <option value="5">A</option>
  <option value="4">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
  <option value="2">D</option>
  <option value="1">E</option>
</select>
```

(**fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zc83L1d5/**)

While I can add an option for "all", it creates a problem because "all" can be selected in combination with any of the other options.

Like I said - functionally, it works fine. It just looks wrong when an item is selected and then unselected because the word "All" goes away.

Any ideas on how to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when you click outside the dropdown after unselecting all options, the word "All" returns again.
It's only because the input-field has focus, that the placeholder "All" isn't showing.

When you keep this in mind, all you have to do to get the placeholder showing again, is let the input-field lose focus when it becomes empty after interaction.

---

**Code snippet (JS, CSS, HTML):**

```js
$(window).on("load",function(){
  $(".chosen-select").chosen();
  $(".chosen-select").on("input change propertychange",function(){
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      $("body").click();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.chosen-select{
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sinkolas.com/v2/funciones/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sinkolas.com/v2/funciones/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sinkolas.com/v2/funciones/FuncionesBellas.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sinkolas.com/v2/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.sinkolas.com/v2/chosen/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select id="xyz" data-placeholder="All" class="chosen-select" multiple="multiple" tabindex="-1">
  <option value="5">A</option>
  <option value="4">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
  <option value="2">D</option>
  <option value="1">E</option>
</select>
```

(**fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zc83L1d5/2/**)

- In my code, I just trigger a click on the `body` element to unfocus from the input-field (even though the cursor is still blinking inside of it). This is not the most elegant solution, but I tried other things like `$(this).blur();`, and nothing worked for me... Maybe you can find another way to remove the focus without having to involve other elements.
- I had to increase the jQuery version (changed it to the highest), because v1.6.4 doesn't recognize `.on("input change propertychange"`.
- I removed the function wrapping `$(".chosen-select").chosen();`, because it is not necessary.
- I changed `multiple=""` to `multiple="multiple"`, because this is just good practice: *In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the multiple attribute must be defined as `<input multiple="multiple" />`*.